# HTML5 Shim - How to dynamically detect if browser needs it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shim

I have a page which uses html5 events via javascript such as the `input` keyboard event on an `<input>` field.

How can I dynamically detect that the browser needs the html5shim, so I can download it only if necessary? I know that I probably have to use the `window.navigator` object or something similar, but I have no ideas besides that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: About 10% of the script is dedicated to doing that already. It isn't worth detecting separately.

Comment: You could check for the existence of `HTMLInputElement.prototype.oninput` but as @Quentin already said, this may not even be necessary.

Comment: I agree with @Quentin - just include the script and let it do it's work.  Bonus points if you include it from a CDN as browser's may already have it cached etc.

Comment: Agreed - no point reinventing the wheel. 99% of your added code could end up redundant

Comment: CDN, if you need it:      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>